# EE channel image 500 error

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have a problem with EE channel image.

I try to save an entry in CP with channel image field. After form submit page do not upadate.

I see a console.log:

> POST admin.php?S=*code*&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=*id* 500(Internal Server Error)

But CP save entry, I can see it in content list.

How can I fix it?

EE v2.7.3; Channel Images v5.1.7

Console.log:

**Headers**

*General*

> *Remote Address*: *IP*
>
> *Request URL*: *site*/admin.php?S=*code*&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=3&entry_id=296&filter=YToxOntzOjEwOiJjaGFubmVsX2lkIjtzOjE6IjMiO30%3D
>
> *Request Method*: POST
>
> *Status Code*: 500 Internal Server Error

*Response Headers*

> *Connection*: keep-alive
>
> *Content-Length*: 624
>
> *Content-Type*: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>
> *Date*: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 09:29:01 GMT
>
> *Server*: nginx/1.0.15

*Request Headers*

> *Accept*: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>
> *Accept-Encoding*: gzip, deflate
>
> *Accept-Language*: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>
> *Cache-Control*: no-cache
>
> *Connection*: keep-alive
>
> *Content-Length*: 5756
>
> *Content-Type*: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>
> *Cookie*: exp_last_visit=1445610390; exp_tracker=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22index%22%3B%7D; _ga=GA1.2.1382217126.1445608211; _gat=1; _ym_visorc_29374685=w; __utmt_UA-64291387-1=1; __utma=118982422.1382217126.1445608211.1445608212.1445851490.2; __utmb=118982422.1.10.1445851490; __utmc=118982422; __utmz=118982422.1445608212.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); exp_last_activity=1445851369; exp_expiration=1445854969; exp_perpage=50; exp_sessionid=921c865100fd0025b3a099bfdaff2405fda412da
>
> *Host*: *site*
>
> *Origin*: *site*
>
> *Pragma*: no-cache
>
> *Referer*: *site*/admin.php?S=*code*&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=3&entry_id=296&&filter=YToxOntzOjEwOiJjaGFubmVsX2lkIjtzOjE6IjMiO30=
>
> *Upgrade-Insecure-Requests*: 1
>
> *User-Agent*: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36

*Query String Parameters*

> *S*: 8d8d8d95caef9e87e0aa070aec817edd
>
> *D*: cp
>
> *C*: content_publish
>
> *M*: entry_form
>
> *channel_id*: 3
>
> *entry_id*: 296
>
> *filter*: YToxOntzOjEwOiJjaGFubmVsX2lkIjtzOjE6IjMiO30=

*Request Payload*

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entry_id"
>
> 296
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="channel_id"
>
> 3
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="autosave_entry_id"
>
> 0
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filter"
>
> YToxOntzOjEwOiJjaGFubmVsX2lkIjtzOjE6IjMiO30=
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="member_group[]"
>
> 1
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="layout_preview"
>
> 1
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"
>
> test 3
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="url_title"
>
> test-3
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_38[data][]"
>
> 5
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_37_hidden_file"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_37_hidden_dir"
>
> 2
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_37"; filename=""
>      Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_37_directory"
>
> 2
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][title]"
>
> 383876254
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][url_title]"
>
> 383876254
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][desc]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][category]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][cifield_1]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][cifield_2]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][cifield_3]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][cifield_4]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][cifield_5]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][imageid]"
>
> 6420
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][filename]"
>
> 383876254.jpg
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][1][cover]"
>
> 0
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][title]"
>
> Dark-noize
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][url_title]"
>
> dark-noize
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][desc]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][category]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][cifield_1]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][cifield_2]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][cifield_3]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][cifield_4]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][cifield_5]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][imageid]"
>
> 0
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][filename]"
>
> dark-noize.jpg
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[images][2][cover]"
>
> 0
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_36[key]"
>
> 1445851731
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_54"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_id_55"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entry_date"
>
> 2015-07-03 05:22 PM
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="expiration_date"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="comment_expiration_date"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="new_channel"
>
> 3
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"
>
> closed
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="author"
>
> 1
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="allow_comments"
>
> y
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pages__pages_uri"
>
> /example/pages/uri/
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pages__pages_template_id"
>
> 49
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"
>
> Submit
>      ------WebKitFormBoundaryhhDtfcNAOo3lgUAH--

Comment: post your error log please

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" status code basically means "see server logs for the actual error message"

Comment: I don't use channel images, but is the "filter" parameter something that goes with it?  It seems strange to me that the value of filter should end with a =.  Is that always the case?  Does the error occur on edit or only on create?